# Laptop keyboard & touchpad not working properly when mouse plugged in

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I have a ubuntu laptop from the brand Tuxedo. When I plug an external mouse in (which works fine on my Windows pc), I can only click into one window - on the mouse, but also the touchpad. Plus the keyboard won't work properly any either. This happens in such random ways that I can't really describe any more precisely. When I pull out the mouse usb cable, everything is fine again.

Comment: Run the following command and paste it's output (It's a little tricky), I'm adding a sleep between 2 `lsusb` commands, after the first command finished and printed to stdout plug in the cable and wait for the second output, try and find the differences between those, the command is: `lsusb && sleep 10 && lsusb`.

Comment: There is no difference except that my mouse shows up on the second list.

Comment: OK, and the mouse and keyboard are not responding with the external mouse is connected yet they appear on the `lsusb` list? Can you try running `udevadm monitor` while plugging and unplugging the mouse?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?